# Google Sheets: Script order only rows where date > today

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Some help will be appreciated. I have the following code:

```
function sort() {

  //Variable for column to sort first
  var sortFirst = 1;
  var sortFirstAsc = true;
  //Variables for column to sort second
  var sortSecond = 2;
  var sortSecondAsc = true;
  //Variables for column to sort third
  var sortThird = 4;
  var sortThirdAsc = true;

  //Number of header rows
  var headerRows = 1; 

  /** Define variables */

  /** Sorting function **/

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows-1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}, {column: sortSecond, ascending: sortSecondAsc}, {column: sortThird, ascending: sortThirdAsc}]);
}
```

It works fine, but now i want to order only when date from column A is TODAY or greater.

[Image of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4BMK.png)
I want to sort below row 3 only.

Any idea how can achieve that?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: So you wish to sort only the rows whose dates are greater than today?  What you want to do with the other dates.  It would be helpful to see an image of your sheet.

Comment: Other dates should remain the same places. I edit the post with an image, i want to order only green rows. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

A possible workaround to solve your isse is to sort only in the range of dates that are today or later. Follow these steps to achieve this:

1. Sort the range in ascending order according to the date column (1).
2. Search for the first item that is equal or higher than today's date.
3. Select a new range that starts from the row of the item we found on the previous step.
4. Execute the sorting function on this new range.

Here is the piece of code to complete this task explained with comments:

```js
function sort() {
  
  //Variable for column to sort first
  var sortFirst = 1;
  var sortFirstAsc = true;
  //Variables for column to sort second
  var sortSecond = 2;
  var sortSecondAsc = true;
  //Variables for column to sort third
  var sortThird = 4;
  var sortThirdAsc = true;
  
  //Number of header rows
  var headerRows = 1; 
  
  /** Define variables */
  
  /** Sorting function **/
  
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows-1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  
  // Sort the whole range by date in ascending order
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  
  // Get the date values of the first column to then compare them to today's date. Flat is used to create a 1D array as getValues() will return a 2D array and to make things simpler
  var getDateValues = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().flat();
  
  // Initialise today's date. As we are only interested on comparing the date, we set the starting time at 00am. We also start a variable to store the index of the row where dates are equal or higher than today. 
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var indexStartRange;
  
  // Loop through all dates values
  for(i=0;i<getDateValues.length;i++){
    
    // Create date object for each value
    var date = new Date(getDateValues[i]);
    
    // if this date is equal or higher than today, then we store the value of its index and break the loop.
    if(date.valueOf() >= today.valueOf() ){
      indexStartRange = i + 2;
      break;
    }
    
  }
  
  // create a final range starting from the row where dates start being equal or higher than today and just run as you did in your example before. 
  var finalRange = sheet.getRange(indexStartRange, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  finalRange.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}, {column: sortSecond, ascending: sortSecondAsc}, {column: sortThird, ascending: sortThirdAsc}]);
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Amazing ! It works !

*Small detail i'm getting this "error": The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the page.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer to solve the issue. In line 46 I should have put ```sheet.getLastRow()``` instead of ```sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows-1``` to get the index of the last row with content. Let me know if that solved the problem :D